# Android + CardView adding margins to non-L versions?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Same layout, but rendering differently between L and all other versions.

**4.1.2**

[image]

**5.0**

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:elevation="40dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:translationZ="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="40dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:text="TEXTVIEW" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Negative margins are inconsistent and not supported in general on Android. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Ignore that negative margin... that was trying to fix the margin that gets added to non-L versions of the CardView.

Comment: I'm attempting to have a similar look between L and non-L using the new CardView.

Comment: Same problem here. Were you able to get a consistent margins between L and pre-L versions?

Answer (score 2):

This is working as intended. The shadows pre-L are "simulated". From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)
"CardView uses elevation property on L for shadows and falls back to a custom shadow implementation on older platforms." There are other compatibility concerns there you should read about. Particularly, make sure to set useCompatPadding to true for consistency.

Comment: Shadow was just one issue, the padding is the big culprit and widely inconsistent. I'm using useCompatPadding, see above.